# How can I make static variable in `module.exports = class` in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I initialize a static variable in `module.exports = class` in node.js.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is, if `StaticVariable` is null, Ill get data from a json file. Then store it in `StaticVariable`.

```
module.exports = class Config { 
    static fetch() {

        if ( StaticVariable === null ) {
            const fs = require('fs');
            const data = fs.readFileSync('./config.json');
            const config = JSON.parse(data);  

            StaticVariable = config;

        }

        return StaticVariable;
    }
}
```

Function `fetch()` will be called several times so it is unnecessary to `readFileSync` every call.

Comment: What problem do you have with this code, besides that you didn't define StaticVariable variable? Static-only class is an antipattern. Is fetch the only member?

Comment: I made `fetch()` as static because I dont want to `new Config`.  @estus

Comment: This doesn't explain why you need a class. *Is fetch the only member?*

Comment: If you are asking if fetch is the only function, it is not.. There will be `new`, `update` etc and will not be a static function. @estus

Comment: Please, update the question with all relevant code and an example how you use Config. Are there supposed to be multiple instances? What you have here seems to be XY problem that could be solved in a better way. Is it necessary to have lazy `fetch`? You could just do `exports.config = require('./config.json')` at the top of the module

Comment: Where is `StaticVariable` defined and how you use `fetch` function ?

Comment: @estus Yeah. I agree this is XY problem, I think Ill just check other ways to go about this. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static-only class is an antipattern in JavaScript because a class is never instantiated.

In case there's a need to have a method that *lazily* loads JSON file, a plain object can be used. There's already such object in module scope, `module.exports`:

```
const fs = require('fs');
let StaticVariable;

exports.fetch = () => {
    if ( StaticVariable == undefined ) { // not "=== null"
        const data = fs.readFileSync('./config.json');
        const config = JSON.parse(data);  

        StaticVariable = config;

    }

    return StaticVariable;
}
```

There may be no need to parse it manually because this could be handled by `require('./config.json')` one-liner and with more consistent relative paths.

In case JSON file can be *eagerly* loaded, this can be simplified to:

```
exports.config = require('./config.json');
```

If there's a need for `Config` class and it should access configuration object, it can refer to it, e.g.:

```
exports.Config = class Config {
  constructor() {
    this.config = deepClone(exports.config);
  }

  modify() {
    // modify this.config
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of several ways to achieve what you are asking.

Saving it in a global variable

```
//initialise it here
var StaticVariable = null;

//however if you initialise it here, it makes more sense to just load it once
const fs = require('fs');
const data = fs.readFileSync('./config.json');
const config = JSON.parse(data);  
StaticVariable = config;

module.exports = class Config { 
    static fetch() {
        return StaticVariable;
    }
}
```

Or just use require. Require will do the same thing what you want to do. It will read the file config.json, try to parse it as a valid json and it will do this only once.

```
module.exports = class Config { 
    static fetch() {
          return require('./config.json');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from (node 15.2.1) ES2020, static private class fields is supported. So from now on static class may not be anti pattern and you can instantiate a class using new keywords. ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/static

```
module.exports = class Config { 
    static #StaticVariable = null;
    static fetch() {    
        if ( StaticVariable === null ) {
            const fs = require('fs');
            const data = fs.readFileSync('./config.json');
            const config = JSON.parse(data);  

            StaticVariable = config;

        }    
        return StaticVariable;
    }
}
```

Where # sign means private more reference can be found in https://node.green, but still the easiest way is described in other answers

```
exports.config = require('./config.json');
```